# Consuming a Stream create using Node.JS

Tags: node.js, express

I have an application, which streams an MP3 using Node.JS. Currently this is done through the following post route...

```
app.post('/item/listen',routes.streamFile)
...
exports.streamFile = function(req, res){
  console.log("The name is "+ req.param('name'))
  playlistProvider.streamFile(res, req.param('name'))
}
...
PlaylistProvider.prototype.streamFile = function(res, filename){
  res.contentType("audio/mpeg3");
  var readstream = gfs.createReadStream(filename, {
      "content_type": "audio/mpeg3",
      "metadata":{
        "author": "Jackie"
       },
       "chunk_size": 1024*4 });
  console.log("!")
  readstream.pipe(res);
}
```

Is there anyone that can help me read this on the client side? I would like to use either JPlayer or HTML5, but am open to other options.

Answer (score 0):

So the real problem here was, we are "requesting a file" so this would be better as a GET request. In order to accomplish this, I used the express "RESTful" syntax '/item/listen/:name'. This then allows you to use the JPlayer the way specified in the links provided by the previous poster.

Comment: Hey, can you specify how you solved this? I have jPlayer and audio files on backend. I want to create real stream and feed it to jPlayer. Hitting a wall with my head for past 2 weeks with this task...

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming you didn't bother visiting [their site](http://jplayer.org/) because had you done so, you would have seen several examples of how to achieve this using HTML5/JPlayer.  The following is a bare-bones example provided by their online developer's documentation:

`<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function() {
          $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            mp3: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-snip-Stirring-of-a-fool.mp3"
          }).jPlayer("play");
          var click = document.ontouchstart === undefined ? 'click' : 'touchstart';
          var kickoff = function () {
            $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("play");
            document.documentElement.removeEventListener(click, kickoff, true);
          };
          document.documentElement.addEventListener(click, kickoff, true);
        },
        loop: true,
        swfPath: "/js"
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="jquery_jplayer_1"></div>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: No specific example? I'm sorry I think you might have misread this, I am not trying to consume an individual file, this is a stream that can only be accessed via a post request. Now maybe I should read more and I would be more than glad to accept specific locations on their websoite, but I have looked and cannot find anything.

Comment: This community is here to offer help, with the assumption that you have done some leg work initially yourself.  For example, had you provided code from one of their many examples and had questions, I would have been more receptive to helping you.

Comment: What example would you have had me emulate? I couldn't find one thats why I posted here. And what is with the unnecessarily hostile disposition?

Comment: If I came across as hostile, it was unintentional.  I am simply not going to google and research for you.  The following is a link to a bare-bones example.  http://jplayer.org/latest/quick-start-guide/example-audio-soundtrack/

Comment: right and this doesn't help me because my stream isn't a hard file like | $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            mp3: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-snip-Stirring-of-a-fool.mp3"
          }).jPlayer("play"); | Instead it is just a POST request with a songname in the form (see code). The argument could be made that this should be more "Restful" and be a get request but I was looking for a more pragmatic solution.

Comment: It does help you and is provided as a bare-bones example.  I was simply illustrating my point that had you done some research and leg work and supplied an example like I did and asked the question, "how might I modify the provided sample to dynamically load a provided file?" people would have been more receptive to aiding you.  There are other examples on their site, which do exactly what you are trying to do and I am confident you can find them.  If you have trouble with something specific, feel free to ask here.